# Minecraft hexxit smeltery glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit, minecraft-tinkers-construct

In the minecraft modpack hexxit, I have build a smeltery (Tinkers' construct). it works fine, I can pour stuff out, it smelts the ores right,... But I have two glitches. One is I can't see the lava level when I look at the smeltery controller (and yes I have actally right-clicked, so I see the screen where you put the ores in). But that one doesn't really bother me. the next one however is a real pain. I have smelted multiple metals. Normally, when you click, the metal you click on, goes to the bottom and it can be poured out. When I click, nothing happens. Are these glitches I can prevent and if yes, how?

Note: English is not my primary language, so there may be a few mistakes in spelling or grammar.

Comment: Try putting the faucet and the drain in a different spot. Also, you need a ingot cast to make ingots, is that maybe what you're missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the same bugs. I think these are just a result of the version of Tinker's Construct that Hexxit currently uses, as the second one is not present in other modpacks I've played that use newer versions. Here are ways I coped with them:

- Lava not displaying in the smeltery GUI: typically, the lava meter on the right of the GUI will appear empty even when lava is in there. The next time the smeltery uses some of it, it should render properly. You don't really have to use this meter though, since the level of lava in the tank block renders properly and you can easily approximate how much is left (it holds 4 buckets when totally full).
- Liquid not moving to the bottom of the smeltery when selected: this bug is a little annoying, since you are forced to always pour whatever is on the bottom first. That's a problem if the amount isn't an integer multiple of an ingot or a block. There are three ways around it:

  1. Pour out whatever nuggets are left on the bottom and get rid of them by breaking the casting table/basin (wasteful, I know).
  2. Always be sure that when you smelt ores or alloys that your result will be an integer multiple of ingots of blocks, then you can empty your smeltery completely every time you use it. Check your in-game TC manuals to get exact ratios needed for creating alloys in integer multiples (can be a little tedious).
  3. You should be able to store molten ore in the same type of tank block that the lava is in, so with a channel system and a series of tanks you can store partial amounts of ore in their own dedicated tanks, keeping your smeltery empty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't fix not being able to swap the metals inside. That's because it's not a glitch. The ability to swap the metals in the smealtery was not added until later versions that are likely not compatible with Hexxit.